# How do I pass an array as a parameter to another script?

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameters, arguments

For some reason, it looks like I cannot pass array of strings as parameter to scriptblock. What am I doing here wrong?

My script which is called from another script:

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]$myarr
)

foreach ($elem in $myarr){
    $elem
}
```

I call it from another script as

```
 $myarr = @("111", "222")
 start-job -filepath myscript.ps1 -arg $myarr
```

I got only the first item in the array - "111".

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try it like below:

```
start-job -filepath myscript.ps1 -arg (,$myarr)
```

The `-ArgumentList` takes in a list/array of arguments. So when you give `-arg $myarr`, it is as though you are passing the elements of the array as the arguments. So you have to force PowerShell to treat it as a single argument which is an array.

Comment: yep, it works. Can you explain why? :) as I understand it comma in () means it is actually an array with two sub arrays, right?

Comment: @Mishkin - Explanation would be that the -ArgumentList takes in a list/ array of arguments. So when you give `-arg $myarr`, it is as though you are passing the elements of the array as the arguments. So you have to force powershell to treat it as a single argument which is an array.

Comment: How would you pass the array and another variable?  -arg (,$myarr, $singleValue).  For the example, $singleValue = "x"

Comment: The problem only happens when try to pass a single array argument, when you pass an array and another argument then you implicitly create another array with the comma. e.g in `-arg $array, $value` the `$array, $value` expression is an array which you can see by evaluating it on the command line. `($arr, 5)[0]` will print $arr; `($arr, 5)[1]` will print 5