# Passing an array of URLs as an argument to Powershell

Tags: parameter-passing, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write a script that will take a text file containing URL links to documents and download them. I am having a hard time understanding how to pass the arguments and manipulate them in powershell. Here is what I got so far. I think I should be using the param method of taking an argument so I can require it for the script, but $args seemed easier on face value... A little help would be much appreciated. 
**UPDATE

```
$script = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
$scriptName = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -replace "(.ps1)" , "")
$scriptPath = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$scriptDirectory = ($scriptPath.Replace("$script" , ""))

## ##################################
## begin code for directory creation.
## ##################################

## creates a direcory based on the name of the script.
do {
    $scriptFolderTestPath = Test-Path $scriptDirectory\$scriptName -PathType container
    $scriptDocumentFolderTestPath = Test-Path $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Documents" -PathType container
    $scriptLogFolderTestPath = Test-Path $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Logs" -PathType container

    if ($scriptFolderTestPath -match "False") { 
        $scriptFolder = New-Item $scriptDirectory\$scriptName -ItemType directory
    }
    elseif ($scriptDocumentFolderTestPath -match "False") {
        New-Item $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Documents" -ItemType directory       
    }
    elseif ($scriptLogFolderTestPath -match "False") {
        New-Item $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Logs" -ItemType directory
    }
} Until (($scriptFolderTestPath -match "True") -and ($scriptDocumentFolderTestPath -match "True") -and ($scriptLogFolderTestPath -match "True"))

## variables for downloading and renaming code.
$date = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)

## ################################
## begin code for link downloading.
## ################################

## gets contents of the arguement variable.
Get-Content $linkList

## downloads the linked file.
Invoke-WebRequest $linkList
```

Resulting Errors

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Website_Download.ps1
cmdlet Website_Download.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
linkList: C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\linkList.txt


    Directory: C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Website_Download


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                     
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                     
d----        10/27/2012   3:59 PM            Website_Download_Script_Documents                                                        
d----        10/27/2012   3:59 PM            Website_Download_Script_Logs                                                             
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\linkList.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Website_Download.ps1:42 char:1
+ Get-Content $linkList
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\linkList.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Invoke-WebRequest : Could not find file 'C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\linkList.txt'.
At C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Website_Download.ps1:45 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest $linkList
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.FileWebRequest:FileWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in passing an array of arguments in Powershell, compared to any other type of arguments. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152740/how-to-pass-an-array-as-a-parameter-to-another-script) for how it's done. Considering you have a text file, you don't need to pass an array of arguments, and only need to pass a file name, so just a string.

I don't have any experience with Powershell 3.0, which is what you are using (judging by the presence of `Invoke-WebRequest` in your code), but I would start with something like this:

```
$URLFile = @"
http://www.google.ca
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.co.uk/
"@

$URLs = $URLFile -split "`n";
$savedPages = @();
foreach ($url in $URLs) {
    $savedPages += Invoke-WebRequest $url   
}
```

That is, you have a single file, all in one place, and make sure you receive your content correctly. Not sure why you would need [`Start-BitsTransfer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819420.aspx), since [`Invoke-WebRequest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) will already get you page contents. Note that I did not do anything with `$savedPages`, so my code is effectively useless.

After that, contents of `$URLFile` goes into a file and you replace a call to it with

```
gc "Path_To_Your_File"`
```

If still working, introduce a `$Path` parameter to your script like this:

```
param([string]$Path)
```

test again, and so on. If you are new to Powershell, always start with smaller code pieces and keep growing to include all functionality you need. If you start with a big piece, chances are you will never finish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This isn't making sense to me though. Why can't I just pass a txt file with URLs as an argument and use the get-content to have each line as an object and pass them to the Invoke-Webrequest cmdlet? I am updating my main post with a param piece I added and the resulting errors.

Comment: @Steve: I am suggesting you a starting point. Forget about external files, forget about parameters. Make sure your single file code works as expected. Yes, you would then pass a txt file with URLs as a parameter, but you don't need to do get-content on URLs. Assuming each line in the file is a URL, you would split by newline and feed into Invoke-Webrequest, which is exactly what I did in my example.

Comment: I don't like this starting point because it's more like a perl script. I shouldn't be parsing the txt file. If I wanted to do this manually it would look like this. '$links = "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\linkList.txt"
$results = "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Results"

$crawl = get-content $links

Invoke-WebRequest $crawl'

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out with the link from Neolisk about handling params. Then changed some code at the end to create another variable and handle things as I normally would. Just some confusion with passing params.

```
## parameter passed to the script.
param (
    [parameter(Position=0 , Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$linkList
)

## variables for dynamic naming.
$script = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)
$scriptName = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name -replace "(.ps1)" , "")
$scriptPath = ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$scriptDirectory = ($scriptPath.Replace("$script" , ""))

## ##################################
## begin code for directory creation.
## ##################################

## creates a direcory based on the name of the script.
do {
    $scriptFolderTestPath = Test-Path $scriptDirectory\$scriptName -PathType container
    $scriptDocumentFolderTestPath = Test-Path $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Documents" -PathType container
    $scriptLogFolderTestPath = Test-Path $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Logs" -PathType container

    if ($scriptFolderTestPath -match "False") { 
        $scriptFolder = New-Item $scriptDirectory\$scriptName -ItemType directory
    }
    elseif ($scriptDocumentFolderTestPath -match "False") {
        New-Item $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Documents" -ItemType directory       
    }
    elseif ($scriptLogFolderTestPath -match "False") {
        New-Item $scriptFolder\$scriptName"_Script_Logs" -ItemType directory
    }
} Until (($scriptFolderTestPath -match "True") -and ($scriptDocumentFolderTestPath -match "True") -and ($scriptLogFolderTestPath -match "True"))

## variables for downloading and renaming code.
$date = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)

## ################################
## begin code for link downloading.
## ################################

## gets contents of the arguement variable.
$webTargets = Get-Content $linkList

## downloads the linked file.
Invoke-WebRequest $webTargets
```

Comment: It does grab the passed param and pull the invoke-webrequest. If the param has multiple lines adding 'Get-Content $linkList | ForEach-Object { Invoke-WebRequest $_ }' For whatever reason I just wasn't passing the param correctly until reading that post and changing things around. Also all my attempts to use $args failed to work correctly.