# ArgumentList parameter in Invoke-Command don't send all array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, invoke-command

First short code, then question

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName someServer

$servicesList = "Service1", "Service2", "Service3"

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Param ($newServicesList)

    Write-Host $newServicesList

} -ArgumentList $servicesList -Session $session

Remove-PSSession  $session
```

The question is why Write-Host in Invoke-Command block give only this output ?

```
Service1
```

Thanks for any answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array to another script with Invoke-Command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577705/passing-array-to-another-script-with-invoke-command) Note: I tested this solution against your script and it fixed the issue.

Comment: @Hyper Anthony - Should I delete the answer if it is duplicate?

Comment: @Mitul: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132600/should-i-delete-my-answer-to-a-question-thats-marked-as-a-duplicate (I wouldn't worry about it, there's nothing wrong with the answer.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You solution is to pass it like `(,$servicesList)`

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName .

$servicesList = "Service1", "Service2", "Service3"

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Param ([string[]]$newServicesList)

    Write-Host $newServicesList

} -ArgumentList (,$servicesList) -Session $session

Remove-PSSession  $session
```

possible explanation from this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152740/how-to-pass-an-array-as-a-parameter-to-another-script).

Comment: Or `-args (,('Service1', 'Service2', 'Service3'))`.  That sucks.