# Invoke-Command Using Local Function With Array As Single Parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a function that takes a single string array as a parameter in my PowerShell .pm1 that I want to be able to call on a remote server using a second function in my .pm1 (I do not want to rely on the server having a copy of the function). I found this [Using Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock on a function with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448808/using-invoke-command-scriptblock-on-a-function-with-arguments) but it only seems to work for 'non-arrays' or for multiple parameters (where array variable is not last)

```
function Hello_Worlds { param([string[]]$persons)
    foreach($person in $persons){
        write-host ("hello "+$person)
    }
}

$people = "bob","joe"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "s1" -ScriptBlock ${function:Hello_Worlds} -ArgumentList $people
#output => "hello bob" only

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "s1" -ScriptBlock ${function:Hello_Worlds} -ArgumentList $people, ""
#output => "hello bob hello joe"
```

I can modify my argument list like `-ArgumentList $people, ""` (above) to make it work by forcing the function to see the $persons variable as a single parameter and not an array of parameters, but that seems like bad practice and I sure that I am just missing something simple.

EDIT:
I was directed here [ArgumentList parameter in Invoke-Command don't send all array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743951/argumentlist-parameter-in-invoke-command-dont-send-all-array) and while it works for this exact example, it requires that I KNOW which parameters require an array. Is there a generic way to pass an any arguments that would prevent this issue? I.E. I build my argument list as an array of parameters and there could be 0 or more of them and any number of them could be arrays - or am I stuck with putting this in front of calls?

```
foreach($parg in $myCustomGeneratedArguments) {
   if($parg -is [array]) {$paramArgs += ,$parg} 
   else {$paramArgs += $parg} 
}
```

Comment: Pass the argument like this `-ArgumentList (, $people)`

Comment: Same purpose to this^,  use it in your assignment: `$people = ,@("bob","joe")`

Comment: Isn't using the ``` , ``` in front the same as using it in the back? This seems as kludgy as ```,""``` or am I missing something?

Comment: Pass the function to the remote host then you can use it inside the scriptblock without any problems. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61273544/15339544. Even tho the answer is for `ForEach-Object -Parallel` it will work the same for `Invoke-Command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I sure that I am just missing something simple.

Unfortunately, you're not (but [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188055/45375) offers an approach that *bypasses* the problem).

The bottom line is this:

- **If you're passing *two or more* - individually specified - arguments to `-ArgumentList`, everything works as expected**, such as  `-ArgumentList $people, ""` in your example.

  - The reason is that the use of `,` *implicitly* creates an *enclosing* array whose elements are the now nested `$people` array, and the empty string (`""`).
- **If you're passing just *one* argument and that one argument happens to be an array (or similar list type) *that must be passed as a whole, as a single argument*, you need the `-ArgumentList (, $arrayOrList)` workaround**, i.e. you need to *explicitly* create an enclosing array, using the *unary* form of `,` the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-), which signals to `-ArgumentList` that `$arrayOrList` doesn't represent *individual* arguments, but a *single* argument that happens to be array-like.
  That is, you're then passing a single-element array whose only element happens to be array-like itself.

Therefore, **you invariably *do* need to know ahead of time if a given array represents *individual arguments* or is a *single, array-valued* argument**.

You can assemble an array of *all* arguments ahead of time in a single array variable, whose elements may or may not be *nested* arrays that should be passed *as a whole*, but there too you need know which elements are themselves array-like and therefore require the use of `,` :

```
$people = "bob", "joe"

# Assembly the list of *all* arguments in a single array variable.
$myArguments = @(
  # Add the $people array as an element, which 
  # requires the unary form of "," *here*.
  , $people
  # Add more elements as situationally needed.
  # ...  
)

# Now you can use $myArguments as-is.
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $function:Hello_Worlds -ArgumentList $myArguments
```

**If you're given a value that you know represents a *single* argument** to pass on, it is **safe to *always* use `-ArgumentList (, $someSingleArgument)`**, whether that single argument happens to be array-like or not.

```
# Assume that $mySingleArgument is a value representing a *single*
# argument, which may or may not be array-like.

Invoke-Command $function:Hello_Worlds -ArgumentList (, $mySingleArgument)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your edit I'm afraid the linked answer doesn't lead you to the *easier path*, which is to not use `-ArgumentList` at all, instead, refer to your `Hello_Worlds` function and to your `$people` array with the [`$using:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#the-using-scope-modifier):

```
function Hello_Worlds { param([string[]]$persons)
    foreach($person in $persons){
        write-host ("hello "+$person)
    }
}

# store the function definition locally
$func   = ${function:Hello_Worlds}.ToString()
$people = "bob","joe"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "s1" -ScriptBlock {
    # define the function in the remote scope
    ${function:Hello_Worlds} = $using:func
    # now you can use it normally
    Hello_Worlds -persons $using:people
}
```