# Wrapper function with same name as command in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am making attempting to fix an app which has recently broken the `ls` command, using a Powershell wrapper script. My wrapper must have the same name as the command it is invoking, so I'm using `invoke-command` to call the original command.

```
# yarn broke 'ls'
function yarn() {
    $modifiedArgs = @()
    foreach ( $arg in $args ) {
        if ( $arg -cmatch '^ls$' ) {
            $arg = 'list'
        }
        $modifiedArgs = $modifiedArgs + $arg
    }
    invoke-command yarn -ArgumentList @modifiedArgs
}
```

However `invoke-command` fails with

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters
```

**How can I run the original command with the modified parameters?**

Edit: I've also tried `-ArgumentList (,$modifiedArgs)` per 
 [Passing array to another script with Invoke-Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577705/passing-array-to-another-script-with-invoke-command) and I still get the same error.

Edit: Looks like `invoke-command` is remoting only. I've also tried `Invoke-Expression "& yarn $modifiedArgs"` but that runs the function itself.

Comment: You want to write a "proxy function". There is some good information on this at [Microsoft's Scripting Guy column](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets/), [Microsoft TechNet's Script Center Repository](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-ProxyCommand-a-simple-9735745e), and [PowerShell With a Purpose (Windows ITPro)](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-proxy-functions#). If you want more info, [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Proxy+command+powershell) may be useful.

Comment: Thanks @JeffZeitlin but this is a binary command: I'm not wrapping other powershell. Even if it was, extracting the code of the original function per the Scripting Guy column seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you can get around needing to specify the full path to the command if you scope the wrapper function to Private:

```
# yarn broke 'ls'
function Private:yarn() {
    $modifiedArgs = @()
    foreach ( $arg in $args ) {
        if ( $arg -cmatch '^ls$' ) {
            $arg = 'list'
        }
        $modifiedArgs += $arg
    }
    & yarn $modifiedArgs
}
```

This will prevent the function from being visible to child scopes, and it will revert back to using the application.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [powershell docs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#Invoke-Item_II) the `&` operator works:

```
# yarn broke 'ls'
function yarn() {
    $modifiedArgs = @()
    foreach ( $arg in $args ) {
        if ( $arg -cmatch '^ls$' ) {
            $arg = 'list'
        }
        $modifiedArgs += $arg
    }
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd' $modifiedArgs
}
```

Still happy to accept other answers that don't involve specifying the command path explicitly.

Comment: `& (gcm yarn -type application -totalcount 1)`