# Pass string array as a parameter to a powersell script using Runtime.exec(...)

Tags: java, arrays, powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

I need to pass a string array as an argument to a PowerShell script from Java using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)`

that array holds some values like:

```java
String[] users = new String[] {"Jon", "Adam"};
```

and the PowerShell script `test.ps1`:

```bsh
param(
  # ... other parameters defined here
  [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [string[]] $names
)

# the rest of the script
```

What is the right way to pass that array?

**Note:**

I tried to a pass in the cmd parameter like that:

1. by passing the argument as a separate tokens without comma:

   ```java
   cmd.add("-names");
   cmd.add("Jon");
   cmd.add("Adam");
   // only "Jon" received in $names
   ```
2. by appending the tokens with comma:

   ```java
   cmd.add("-names")
   cmd.add("Jon"
   cmd.add(","
   cmd.add("Adam");
   // only "Jon" received in $names
   ```
3. by appending the arguments as a comma-separated string:

   ```java
   cmd.add("-names");
   cmd.add("Jon, Adam");
   // single string received contains "Jon, Adam"
   ```
4. by appending parameter and comma-separated arguments as a single string:

   ```java
   cmd.add("-names Jon, Adam");
   // return an error
   ```

but none of the above is working.

**Update 1:**

I know now that I can pass the arguments on two ways from the console:

```bsh
test.ps1 -names Jon,Adam
test.ps1 -names ("Jon","Adam")`
```

and I tried to pass the array like:

```java
cmd.add("-names")
cmd.add("(\"Jon\", \"Adam\")");
```

but that also isn't working. The script receives them as a single string!

Comment: And what do you expect to receive if you issue a "echo $names"?

Comment: @PetSerAl you are right, it's a typo and I updated the question

Comment: @Heri, I expect to see both names in that array [I updated the script in the question]

Comment: maybe this anwer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152740/how-to-pass-an-array-as-a-parameter-to-another-script

Comment: @Heri It should work if I'm passing it form another script, but it's a different case

Comment: the script does not know where the arguments come from. The linked answer above suggest to embed the given array into parantheses. I would  pass it to the Runtime args as one string (with the parantheses).

Comment: @Heri I got your point, I'll try that

Comment: @Heri I still can't make it work, please check 'Update #1' section

Comment: sorry, I have no further tip

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the arguments twice. My Java is a little rusty, but I think something like this should do:

```java
String[] users = new String[] {"Jon", "Adam"};
String script = "C:/path/to/your.ps1"
String cmd = "powershell.exe " + script + " -names " +
             "\"'" + String.join("'\",\"'", users) + "'\"";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```