# How do I run parallel foreach loop?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run some script in Powershell Core (no workflow, no -Parallel option for ForEach).

So I'm trying to split my array in batches and run them at parallel. So I do:

```
$iterCount = 150000;
$threadCount = 8;
$batchSize = $iterCount/$threadCount;

$block = {
    Param($range)

    Foreach ($i in $range) {
        ...
    }
}

For ($i = 0; $i -lt 150000; $i += $batchSize) {
    Start-Job -Scriptblock $block -ArgumentList $i..$i+$batchSize
}
```

But when I call it I get

```
Start-Job : Cannot bind parameter 'InitializationScript'. Cannot convert the "..                                        0+18750" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.Scr                                        iptBlock".
At /home/tchain/dit/push_messages3.ps1:63 char:48
+     Start-Job -Scriptblock $block -ArgumentList $i..$i+$batchSize
+                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Job], ParameterBindingExce                                        ption
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co                                        mmands.StartJobCommand
```

It seems that `ArgumentList` stringifies everything so I cannot pass a range.

Is there a way to pass strongly typed range? Is there any better way to parallelize loop? I'd like to write `(0..150000).AsParallel().ForEach($i => ...)` But it seems that I can't.

I did `Param([int] $from, [int] $to)` as a workaround, but I'm not sure if it's the best I can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Powershell Run Commands in Parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016451/can-powershell-run-commands-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of evaluating a range operator in argument list, use temp variables to create an array of desired size. Then pass the array as an argument. Like so,

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt 150000; $i += $batchSize) {
    $j = $i+$batchSize
    $range = $i..$j
    Start-Job -Scriptblock $block -ArgumentList (,$range)
}
```

Edit: `-ArgumentList` unravels the array, so [a bit trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153001/503046) is needed.

Test code via printing details about passed array:

```
$block = {
  Param([array]$range)
  write-host "len`t[0]`t[-1]"
  write-host $range.length"`t"$range[0]"`t"$range[-1]
}

For ($i = 0; $i -lt 150000; $i += $batchSize) {
    $j = $i+$batchSize
    $range = $i..$j
    Start-Job -Scriptblock $block -ArgumentList (,$range)
}

get-job | receive-job
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    0       18750
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    18750   37500
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    37500   56250
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    56250   75000
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    75000   93750
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    93750   112500
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    112500          131250
len     [0]     [-1]
18751    131250          150000
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work: only one iteration performs

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Oops, forgot the parameter unravel. See edited version.

Answer (score 0):

The range operator ".." literally creates an array of that many integers.  Just like ""$array += element", "1..$highnumber" can use a lot of memory.  A for loop should work fine in the job.  You also never use $iterCount.

Also note that jobs use new processes.  But you can use start-threadjob instead in PS 6, to use threads.

```
#$iterCount = 150000;                                                                                                                                 
$iterCount = 24
$threadCount = 8;
$batchSize = $iterCount/$threadCount;

$block = {
    Param($start,$range)
    "start $start range $range"
    For ($i = $start; $i -lt $range; $i++) {
        $i 
    }
}

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $iterCount; $i += $batchSize) {
    Start-Job -Scriptblock $block -ArgumentList $i,($i+$batchSize)
}


start 0 range 3
0
1
2
start 3 range 6
3
4
5
start 6 range 9
6
7
8
start 9 range 12
9
10
11
start 12 range 15
12
13
14
start 15 range 18
15
16
17
start 18 range 21
18
19
20
start 21 range 24
21
22
23
```

For purposes of comparison, actually creating the range ".." within the scriptblock.  Output from receive-job may appear out of order.

```
$iterCount = 150000                                                                   
$threadCount = 8
$batchSize = $iterCount/$threadCount

$block = {
    Param($start,$range)
    "start $start range $range"                                      
    Foreach ($i in $start..($range-1)) {
        # $i                                                                          
    }
}

For ($i = 0; $i -lt $iterCount; $i += $batchSize) {
    Start-Job -Scriptblock $block -ArgumentList $i,($i+$batchSize)
}


start 0 range 18750
start 18750 range 37500
start 75000 range 93750
start 131250 range 150000
start 93750 range 112500
start 37500 range 56250
start 56250 range 75000
start 112500 range 131250
```