Powershell invoke-command: why isn't this engaging the foreach loop?
OK, I'm piggybacking off my previous question Powershell script to get IIS app pool recycling time from servers and wondering what I'm doing wrong
I have a list of IIS app pools (apppools.txt) and a list of servers (servers.txt)
When I run it as written below, the only output I get is the FIRST app pool from the list for each node. Can anybody help me find my (probably very simple) mistake?
Output example:

"ServerName","AppPool","RecycleTime" 
"serverS26","Pool1","04:10:00" 
"serverS27","Pool1","04:10:00" 

When I would expect to get about 10 app pools and their respective recycling times. I'm sure it's something stupid with my ICM Params or arguments.
$apppools =gc c:\temp\apppools.txt
$servers = Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt
foreach ($server in $servers){
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -argumentlist @($apppools) -scriptblock {

param($apppools)
$servername = hostname
$infoObject = New-Object PSObject

import-module webadministration

foreach ($a in $apppools){

$recycle = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$a" -Name recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection).value.tostring()}


Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "ServerName" -value $Servername
Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "AppPool" -value $a
Add-Member -inputObject $infoObject -memberType NoteProperty -name "RecycleTime" -value $recycle

$infoObject
} | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, RunspaceId, PSShowComputerName | Export-Csv -append -path  "C:\temp\recycling.csv" -NoTypeInformation 

}


There's an odd workaround for invoke-command and array arguments (,$apppools) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152740/how-do-i-pass-an-array-as-a-parameter-to-another-script-start-job

Yeah, I'm obviously not a PS expert. thanks for the link. I tried adding the , but no luck.
You mentioned an odd workaround-- how should I have done it? I cobbled this together from other scripts.

Applying the technique from the linked duplicate to your case means: Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -argumentlist (, $apppools) ...

Also invoke-command -computername $servers would run faster.

And yes @js2010, it would run faster but I prefer it in series

@dbutts, please don't fundamentally change your question after answers have been given, as it invalidates the latter. After solving the initial problem - as noted in my comments, passing (, $apppools) is enough - you ran into an unrelated follow-up problem, which  you can simply solve as follows: place the $infoObject = New-Object PSObject statement inside your foreach ($a in $apppools) loop.

As an aside: Consider the more efficient and convenient [pscustomobject] @{ ... } syntax for constructing custom objects - see about_PSCustomObject.

thank you @mklement0. I didn't know how to repost my 'new code' in order to show my changes.  I moved the $infoobject inside the foreach loop--- getting closer, now it gives me only the LAST app pool.

I missed that you also need to move the $infoObject statement into the foreach loop; here's a minimal example: foreach ($a in 1..3) { $infoObject = new psobject; $infoObject | Add-Member foo ('bar'+$a) ; $infoObject }

@mklement0 THAT'S THE WINNER-- now i get exactly what I need! Thank you and everyone else so very much for your help. Is  there a correct way for me to give you credit for all of your help?
somewhat related, i hope i can convert this into a script that can actually update the recycle times :)

@dbutts, glad to hear it. No need for credit in this case, thanks. If you have a follow-up question, please create a new question post (though I suspect this may have been asked before, so look for existing posts first).

I suspect your parameters to Invoke-Request are getting splatted. Basically you need to be more explicit defining variable types to avoid these types of issues. When running Invoke-Command on a remote system your single array of strings variable is interpreted as multiple positional variables being passed to the script block. As your only defining a single named argument param($apppools) in your script block your only seeing the 1st value in the original array.
I've made a few changes to your code below that i think should solve your issue:

Forcing $apppools to be of type [string[]] (instead of Object[]).
Specifying the type of the value passed to -ArgumentList - Using ([Object[]] @(,$apppools)) instead of @($apppools) ensures you pass an [Object[]] ie an object array with 1 element. And that element is your array of app pool name strings (of type [string[]]).
Ive set the type of $apppools inside the script block to [String[]]
GC is Get-Content so updated for consistency only. The type of $servers doesnt really matter as that doesn't get passed to your script block, but again updated for consistency.

[string[]] $apppools = Get-Content c:\temp\apppools.txt
[string[]] $servers = Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt
foreach ($server in $servers){
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList ([Object[]] @(,$apppools)) -ScriptBlock {
    param([String[]] $apppools)

(im not sure if only #2 might actually be required, but the rest is good practice to avoid weird issues with type conversion :)

As a side note, if you litter your code with write-host's, you can get any variables type, and if its an array, you can get its length like this:
Write-Host $apppools.GetType()
Write-Host $apppools.Length

I think to get any output from the script block you would need to include Start-Transcript -Path $logfilepath at the start of the block. The path/filename in $logfilepath will be created on the remote computer though.

Good analysis of the original problem, but none of the casts are needed, as this example demonstrates: Invoke-Command { param($apppools) foreach ($ap in $apppools) { "[$ap]" } } -ArgumentList (, ('foo', 'bar'))

My assumption was the -ComputerName $server part is changing the behavior somehow. The OP said they tried -argumentlist (, $apppools) (where $apppools is of type Object[] from GC) but it didnt work? The linked answer is only executing stuff locally, so i assumed theres a type conversion gone bad somewhere, but im unable to test

No, the use of -ComputerName and the resultant remote execution don't make a difference, given that [string] values are serialized with type fidelity. You can test this with "loopback remoting" from an elevated session as follows: Invoke-Command { param($apppools) foreach ($ap in $apppools) { "[$ap]" } } -ArgumentList (, ('foo', 'bar')) -ComputerName localhost, localhost

Thank you @MisterSmith I have reposted the script above along with the errors it now throws. And the output file still only shows the first app pool of each server.

@dbutts: As noted in the comments on the question (which I've reverted to its previous state to avoid confusion), the error you're seeing now is an unrelated follow-on error, the solution to which is noted above.

@MisterSmith, as for producing output from the remotely executing script block: the $infoObject line in isolation inside the app-pool foreach loop is what produces output (1 object per iteration, once the fix is applied).
